# i want to do same thing for three lists can I pass both to one map?

Tags: python

I want to multiply my lists numbers with 2 but I have to write same code for each one so I tried to pass all lists to one map but i get type error:

```
   list_1 = [1,2,3,4]
   list_2 = [5,6,1,2]
   list_3 = [10,20,30]
   
   multipleNum =map(lambda x : x*2,list_1,list_2,list_3)

   print(list(multipleNum))
```

is there a way to use one map or i must to write three map.

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: Why do you want to use `map` for this? Have you heard of a *list comprehension*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct the only thing you missed is that the second argument to the mapmust be an `iterator` and the `lambda` funciton is going to get  a list as an argument so you'll have to treat the input as a list and not a list item.Just try making the following changes:

```py
    list_1 = [1,2,3,4]
    list_2 = [5,6,1,2]
    list_3 = [10,20,30]
   
    multipleNum = map(lambda x : [y*2 for y in x],[list_1,list_2,list_3])    # pass all the list inside a single list and change the kambda function

    print(list(multipleNum))
```

the above code will output:

```py
    [[2, 4, 6, 8], [10, 12, 2, 4], [20, 40, 60]]
```